# Yum Changelog Plugin

Tags: yum, plugin

I installed `yum-changelog` for viewing package change logs before and after updates,but get different error. I use these commands:

```
yum changelog 2018-Mar yum\*
yum update samba-client --changelog
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post that?

Comment: for "yum changelog 2018-Jan yum\* "get the this error:                    No such command: changelog. Please use /bin/yum --help
It could be a DNF plugin command, try: "dnf install 'dnf-command(changelog)'"                                                                                                  for "yum update samba-client --changelog" get this one:  dnf upgrade: error: unrecognized arguments: --changelog

Comment: It seems like `yum` is linked to the newer package manager, `dnf`, on your system based on the errors you are receiving. `dnf` does not have a `--changelog` plugin, but it does have an `updateinfo` command. I would try using `dnf updateinfo --info  samba-client`.

Comment: I get errors unless I run yum changelog with sudo (i.e. `sudo yum changelog`)